# Is there an easy way to standardize .bib entries with JabRef?

Tags: bibtex, bibliography

For example, I discovered that one journal title is "Journal of X" for some .bib entries, but "*The* Journal of X" for other entries (they should all include "*The*"). Or an author is "John Public" for some entries, but "John *Q.* Public." for other entries.

I noticed that if I type .bib entries there is autocomplete, but I almost exclusively import entries from the web, which short-circuits this tool.

Can JabRef standardize these entries? Or should I reply on find-replace my text editor?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

bibclean checks syntax and fixes the author ordering, among other things.

JabRef has an option to abbreviate and unabbreviate an entries' journal name based on ISO or MEDLINE. You could try converting to abbreviations and back?

If you want authors names to be abbreviated then you can use the following in your latex file

\bibliographystyle{abbrv}